# Salvage files from ext3 filesystem with physical errors

Tags: linux, data-recovery, ext2

I have a disk from a crashed Linux laptop with files on it that the unhappy owner would like to have back if at all possible (no backup solutions please).  I have not had anything to do with it before. The disk is recognized by both OS X and Ubuntu 11.10:

```
root@ubuntu1110:~# fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x80d549b4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          63   953602334   476801136   83  Linux
/dev/sdc2       953602335   976768064    11582865    5  Extended
/dev/sdc5       953602398   976768064    11582833+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

This looks consistent with a stock installation of a Linux distribution with a swap partition.

Unfortunately some rather nasty messages show up in dmesg, after Ubuntu says it cannot mount the sdc1 partition:

```
[  181.228092] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
[  181.232176] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  181.232181] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 21 00 00 00
[  181.236359] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[  181.236364] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  181.246696] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[  181.246707] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  182.835915]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 < sdc5 >
[  182.854199] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[  182.854204] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  182.854208] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[  218.250174] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled sense code
[  218.250179] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  218.250182] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  218.250187] Info fld=0x0
[  218.250188] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  218.250193] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 08 00 00 08 00
[  218.250200] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 264
[  218.250206] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 33
[  255.398994] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled sense code
[  255.399029] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  255.399032] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  255.399037] Info fld=0x0
[  255.399038] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  255.399053] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 08 00 00 08 00
[  255.399061] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 264
[  255.399066] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 33
[  281.340599] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled sense code
[  281.340609] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  281.340618] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[  281.340653] Info fld=0x0
[  281.340655] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  281.340659] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 67 00 00 08 00
[  281.340667] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 103
[  281.340739] EXT3-fs (sdc1): error: can't read group descriptor 4
```

My current theory is that the harddisk has run out of spare blocks so now a real bad block has been introduced and it is in the area used when mounting the partition.  This is confirmed by dd:

```
root@ubuntu1110:~# dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/dev/null bs=10240 conv=noerror
dd: reading `/dev/sdc1': Input/output error
2+0 records in
2+0 records out
20480 bytes (20 kB) copied, 44.7084 s, 0.5 kB/s
dd: reading `/dev/sdc1': Input/output error
9+1 records in
9+1 records out
96256 bytes (96 kB) copied, 162.933 s, 0.6 kB/s
dd: reading `/dev/sdc1': Input/output error
9+1 records in
9+1 records out
96256 bytes (96 kB) copied, 180.083 s, 0.5 kB/s
```

Bad blocks early and very slow transmission rate even later in the process (not shown)

My problem now is how to approach from here.  I need something that can read from a broken ext2/ext3-filesystem so we can copy those files still there off the disk, and I have not done much Linux system administration in the last 15 years so I do not know the right terms for searching.

I could probably copy a disk image over night, but then the "this block is bad" information is lost.

What kind of program would be useful in this situation?

Answer (score 6):

First rule of disk recovery: **Stop using the disk.**  If there are hardware issues (such as a head crash), any usage risks further damage; if the filesystem is corrupt, any `mount` or `fsck` has the potential to make it worse.  (Even in `ro` mode!  Note that `mount -t ext3 -o ro` *will* attempt to playback the journal and write to disk!)

Use [dd_rescue](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/) or [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) to copy as much of the disk image to another system as possible, put the disk away, and make copies of the image.  Perform all attempts at recovery from one of the copies.

Now, I gave some tips for ext data recovery [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35594).  In short,

- Your partition layout appears to be still valid.  If it weren't, you could use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or [gpart](http://www.brzitwa.de/mb/gpart/index.html) to attempt recovery of the partition table.
- [e2fsck](http://git.kernel.org/?p=fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git;a=tree;hb=HEAD) may be able to munge the filesystem back into a mountable state.  It'll place dangling inodes into `/lost+found` and report errors.
- [ext4magic](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/ext4magic/) tries to recover data from journaled metadata.  Whether files are recoverable from the journa is up to luck and chance, but it's possible there's stuff in there.
- [The Sleuth Kit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/) can parse and output most filesystem structures.  If you know a fair amount about the filesystem's internal layout and have a hex editor handy (to do stuff like "superblock is corrupt and backup superblock is out of date but I can pick enough data out to reconstruct it myself"), IMO this is the absolutely most useful tool for recovering the most data.
- [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) will attempt to find byte sequences that look like files.  It is only guessing at file start/end, will not know anything about the filesystem structure such as directories and filenames,  and will not find fragmented files.

Comment: +1 for dd_rescue or ddrescue. It's a basic tool to salvage everythink you can!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've gone through all the usual pros and cons of professional data recovery services, you've weighed the cost of the lost data against the risk of doing it yourself... the user decided the data was not worth $000's, but it *is* worth hours and hours of your time...

Here's what I would do.

- Try to do the overnight dd image and set the disk aside
- use Testdisk against the image file http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

If I got 0.5kB/s consistently on the dd, it's probably not worth your time to attempt this.

You *could* run Testdisk against the disk.  It *might* work.  If cost/risk dictates no other options, then... it's your call.  It might work.

In general, seriously, these problems are a political minefield.  The user is either too embarassed to ask their coworkers to re-send their files, or they don't want to face their management and admit that they didn't run regular backups, and now they need to spend thousands on data recovery.  They're hoping that maybe you can fix it for them and make all their problems go away... and if the drive self-destructs in the process.  THEY WILL THROW YOU UNDER THE BUS to save their own skin.

Comment: This is a private person without a lot of money and I am explicitly doing her a favor!  What is your experience with TestDisk?

Comment: It's primarily concerned with analysing the structure of the disk and will let you do stuff like manually mount disks, specify filesystem types, manually scan for superblocks, etc.  There's another sister utility called "photorec" which looks for signatures of the data.  E.g., if a .doc file is on the disk, it will follow the blocks and recover the file even if there is no superblock.  Photorec is probably impractical unless you can get better transfer rates or take the dd.  I've used these to do data recovery, but I'm not a data recovery professional.